# @tailrec optimisation and @Advice.OnMethodEnter behaviour

Tags: java, scala, byte-buddy

I want to instrument a Scala method that is annotated with `@tailrec`. This causes the compiler to optimize the recursive method to a loop as long as it is tail recursive.

For example:

```scala
  @tailrec
  private def tailRecFunction(i: Int): Unit = {
    if (i > 0) {
      println(s"$i on Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId}")
      Thread.sleep(20)
      tailRecFunction(i - 1)
    } else {
      println(s"0 on Thread ${Thread.currentThread().getId}")
      Thread.sleep(20)
      ()
    }
  }
```

And I have the method adviced as follows:

```scala
        @Override
        public ElementMatcher<? super MethodDescription> getMethodMatcher() {
            return named("tailRecFunction");
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable.class, inline = false)
        public static void onEnter() {
            logger.info("onMethodEnter");
        }

        @Advice.OnMethodExit(suppress = Throwable.class, inline = false)
        public static void onExit() {
            logger.info("onMethodExit");
        }
```

This causes the following log-output for `tailRecFunction(10)`:

```
2021-08-01 22:28:03,364 [main] INFO onMethodEnter
10 on Thread 1
9 on Thread 1
8 on Thread 1
7 on Thread 1
6 on Thread 1
5 on Thread 1
4 on Thread 1
3 on Thread 1
2 on Thread 1
1 on Thread 1
0 on Thread 1
2021-08-01 22:28:03,633 [main] INFO onMethodExit
```

Would there be any way on how I could instrument this method and actually get the `onMethodEnter` and `onMethodExit` call on every method call instead of one enter and exit?

Comment: _"This causes the compiler to optimize the recursive method..."_ **Not** true. The optimization happen whether the annotation is there or not. The annotation simply halts compilation if the method is _not_ tail recursive.

Comment: _"and actually get the onMethodEnter and onMethodExit call on every method call instead of one enter and exit"_ It is called on every method call though. Due to tail recursion optimization you have only one.

Comment: Why are you even asking this, after you said yourself that instead of a recursive function, the tail optimisation creates a loop? There are no recursive methods calls which Byte Buddy could intercept for you. You want to keep the cake, but also eat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because tail call elimination means, at the bytecode level,  that there's only one entry and exit (in terms of execution) of the method, for a tool like Byte Buddy which works at the level of the byte code can only ever see one entry/exit.

Note that Byte Buddy is designed for Java: it only really understands bytecode which would be similar to what a Java compiler would emit.  If Byte Buddy can instrument loop entry and exit, it might be able to work with a tail recursive method in Scala.

As far as I know, there's no annotation or compiler option to disable tail call elimination in Scala, so this couldn't be accomplished with Byte Buddy.  Assuming that you're trying to augment code which you own, it might be possible to instrument every iteration via a macro.

Comment: Scala does not perform tail call elimination (because JVM does not support it). It can only do loop optimisation of tail recursive functions, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Loop optimization of tail recursive functions is tail call elimination (albeit a limited form).  It's not general tail call elimination (performing TCE for every case where it can).

Comment: Tail call elimination is a local optimisation that creates a valid call stack but uses the caller's address on the stack rather than the function's address. The target function is still "called" in that it has to save registers and extract data from the stack each time. It can be done without knowledge of the code in the called function. Recursive loop optimisation is a full function optimisation that re-writes the AST to avoid any stack access or register saves and really is a very different optimisation.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call: "The special case of tail recursive calls, when a function calls itself, may be more amenable to call elimination than general tail calls."  Encoding a tail-call as a jump (thus eliminating the call) is the definition of tail-call elimination (per Steele) and is orthogonal to saving registers (with a caller-save convention, for instance, tail-call elimination eliminates register saves, which is why, IIRC, Steele & Sussman preferred caller-save in Scheme).

Comment: Not a great fan of that article, but I do see your point. I guess I am just making the point that Scala does not implement generic tail call elimination, it only eliminates tail calls as part of a broader optimisation in one specific situation.